# stop R process without closing console?

Tags: r, process, console

I've accidentally initiated a long process in R without saving what I need from the workspace I'm using in the R console.  I would like to stop the current process without closing the console.  But, what always happens in an intensive process is that the R Console will not respond.  I will then either have to wait or exit out of the console.  I am running 64 bit R 2.15.0 and my OS is Windows 7 64-bit.  Is there some way to kill R processes outside the R environment and not close the console?

Comment: ESC button has always worked for me (same OS and previously, that version of R, using the standard GUI). I'm not sure where the documentation for this is.

Comment: I've always used the stop button, and it works fine on short processes.  The ones I have trouble are things that take 10 minutes or so computing time (e.g. mixed model on a larger data set).  I'll try your suggestion with a toy example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'stop' button only "works" if the code in question has interrupt points.  I'm vague on the exact implementation of such interrupts (especially when running code which calls c or FORTRAN funcs), but that's why it happens.
If you check the TaskManager -- or whatever that `<CTRL>-<ALT>-<DEL> , <ALT>-T` app is called, you'll see there are no subprocesses.  There's just `R`.